# Allow specific file in htaccess that is rewriting all subdirectories

Tags: php, .htaccess

Not sure if I titled my question accurately.  I have a directory structure like this:

`example.com/edit/43424242/`

Where the number at the end is not actually a folder.  It's really just a variable that I want to use at the `/edit/index.php` directory.

I tried using this in my .htaccess file at the root directory:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^edit/(.*)/?$ edit/index.php?var=$1 [NC,L]
```

But that didn't work because it messes up my AJAX post to another file in that directory `/edit/post.php`

So I thought maybe I need to modify my .htaccess file so that I can still retrieve the subdirectories as a variable and still be able to use post.php or perhaps modify .htaccess so that it allows index.php to communicate with post.php.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
```

It is not enough for check for empty query string as it will not prevent this rule affecting serving real files and directories.

You may use this rule:

```sh
RewriteEngine ON

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^edit/([\w-]+)/?$ edit/index.php?var=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```